# Craft Commerce 2, turning on debug bar and getting error

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

Craft Commerce 2, turning on debug bar and getting an error. 
"Invalid Configuration, Payment currency not allowed."

Could anyone shed any light of this error please?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete all active carts in the control panel and the errors will go away.

You changed the base currency and some exisiting carts are referencing a non exisiting currency. This should only be happening in development as you wouldn’t change the base currency for an existing site.

Comment: I’m the next release if the base currency changes we will update all active carts.

Comment: Fantastic. That fixed the problem. Thanks.